# Find records based on ID which dont/do exist

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I am in need to report when an employee has no time entered in a time card stored in a table called employee_time et.

My issue is to find people who have not entered time for said week.

I have used the NOT IN to find employee IDs that do not exist in the table, thus if record does not exist no time has been entered. This work well.

```
Select
     e.userName,
     et.dateStart,
     et.dateEnd

From  employee_time et,
      employee e
Where
      e.employee_id NOT IN (Select employee_id from employee_time
                            where et.dateStart = date and
                                  et.end_date = date)
Group by 
      e.userName,
      et.startDate,
      et.endDate
```

The issue is in the application when a person navigates to the employee time entry page it create a record for the employee, if the employee does not enter any time the result is a record with ZERO hours. But the record does now exist. Thus will not be found in the above query, I have used the following to find records whose totals = 0

```
Select
     e.userName,
     et.dateStart,
     et.dateEnd,
     SUM(et.hoursTotal) AS total

From  employee_time et,
      employee e
Where
      e.employee_id = et.employee_id and
      et.hours_total = 0
Group by 
      e.userName,
      et.startDate,
      et.endDate
```

This also works well, however I need to marry them but have been unsuccessful to date. Can you help?

Comment: What actual output do you want from the "marriage" of these two queries?

Comment: You want to treat records with `hours_total` = 0 as if they didn't exist? `where hours_total <> 0`?

Comment: My desired output is the employee_ids, so I am able to access the user name and place in a report that said person did not enter time.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but the first query is just horrible. You do know that you are cross joining the tables, don't you? And if you want to show employee IDs, why do you show dtateStart and dateEnd? What are these fields supposed to contain in your results?

Comment: You are correct my cross join is acting as an inner join, and my dates are parameters for my reporting tool Jasper.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
     e.userName,
     et.dateStart,
     et.dateEnd,
     SUM(et.hoursTotal) AS total

From  
      employee e left outer join employee_time et on (e.employee_id = et.employee_id)
 -- Where nvl(et.hours_total,0) = 0
Group by 
      e.userName,
      et.startDate,
      et.endDate
having SUM(et.hoursTotal) > 0
```

If you don't want having you can use commented where this should be the same

if you want only employee_ids:

```
select e.empolyee_id 
from employee e left outer join employee_time et on (e.employee_id = et.employee_id)
Where nvl(et.hours_total,0) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The general format will be something like this:

```
Select employee_id
  From employee
Minus
Select employee_id
  From TableExpressionEliminatesOnMissingDates
Minus
Select employee_id
  From TableExpressionEliminatesOnSummarization;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
Select e.userName
From employee e
Where e.employee_id NOT IN (Select employee_id
                            from employee_time
                            where et.dateStart = $date and
                                  et.end_date = $date and 
                                  et.hoursTotal > 0
                           );
```

You are starting with the date as input, so I don't see why you need it in the output as well.  If you do, I would go for:

```
Select e.userName, w.*
From employee e cross join
     (select distinct et.dateStart, et.end_date
      from employee_time et
      where $date between et.dateStart and et.dateEnd
     ) w
Where e.employee_id NOT IN (Select et.employee_id
                            from employee_time et
                            where $date between et.dateStart and et.dateEnd and
                                  et.hoursTotal > 0
                           );
```

Note:  Avoiding the `GROUP BY` in the outer query is a win in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

The following query finds all employees that have no valid entry in employee_time for the given start and end date:

```
select * 
from employee
where employee_id not in
(
  select employee_id 
  from employee_time
  where datestart = :date_start
    and end_date = :date_end
    and hours_total > 0
);
```

Comment: Thorsten, this is correct, but I also need the people who never accessed the employee_time table thus no records exist of them.

Comment: The query is looking for employees that have no valid entry in employee_time in the given time range. This is also true for employees that have no records at all in the table of course. Have you even tried the query?